# Is there a standard for Album Art?

Tags: album-art

I using a couple of methods to assign the artwork to my music files. The source images ranges from really small ones e.g. 100px X 100px to bigger ones like 500px (all jpegs). Somehow, they don't always appear (e.g. on my walkman phone or my wife's ipod), but they do appear on my PC media player.

I'm wondering is it due to the size, aspect ratio or other reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it depends.  The images iTunes downloads are all consistent, but linux players like Amarok look for Album art from Amazon - it basically does a keyword search and whatever images it can find it makes available as album art choices.  Those images are all sorts of sizes and formats.

As far as players, some older players had a resolution of 176x132 pixels versus the newer 320x240.  The iPod touch has 480x320.

Answer (score 1):

Which media player do you use ? Windows Media Player, IIRC, picks up album art and stores them as `folder.jpeg` or `AlbumArtSmall.jpg` in the folder where the music files exist.

Comment: I use Windows Media Player. I thought the jpegs are embedded into the music files, no?

Comment: They can be embedded, not sure if WMP reads the embedded album art.All of my music collection has a folder.jpg + embedded album art

Comment: "All of my music collection HAVE*..." Please pardon the error.

Answer (score 0):

80x80 pixels, plain and simple.

Comment: Ah... I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You said that your album art **dont appear**. Simple suggestions -

1. Always use ones whose resolutions are **above 250** pixels.
2. Make sure that they have an aspect ration of 1:1 or black/white bands will appear depending on the device.
3. Tag them, don't use WMP as it assigns 200x200 ones no matter what the original image resolution.

That ought to do it.